# How to model to improve the room usage efficiency based on motion sensor history

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, predictive-models, inference

To reduce the confusion, I changed my application from traffic to meeting room, so this application is about modeling a meeting room efficiency , the data collection is built by placing a kind of motion sensor at the center of room for detecting and counting the motion activities. So my data are time-series based for the motion activities.

The model I want to build is for the purpose of optimizing the time length for showing the people the status of room being occupied or not. If a sensor receives motion event at the moment, in order to decide how long to show the occupied status, the application would look back the history of motion events, (say last 5 minutes)

In case if counting 20 consecutive motion events in the last 5 minutes, then it means there was high density of activities, so I would assume the room was busy and will be busy in the next consecutive minutes, then make the occupied status time stay longer time (5 minutes) before it turns to free status

If in cases that in the last 5 minutes, only 2 events being monitored, then it means the room might be not busy, then make this occupied status time stay only 1 minute.

So far I'm only concerned about what kind of statistical model should I use to predict the how long the occupied time length based on the latest 5 minutes'motion history?

Comment: i dont think you can optimize just on traffic light. they should work in concert

Comment: If in the last 2 minutes, there is 50 cars passed, then I can say make the green light last for 2 minutes. on the contrary, in the last 2 mintues, there is only 10 cars passed, I can make the green light last shorter, say 1 minute. is it simple to understand, why can't model it

Comment: if you don't know what other light are doing, then you can actually mess up their work, in my opinion. you let the car pass, then it gets stuck in the next light.

Comment: You also need to consider pedestrian and bike traffic. I would be upset if I had to wait 4 minutes to cross a road.

Comment: Thank you, aksakal for your concern. But right now to begin, I just want to make it simplified as much as possible, that only one road and one traffic light existed, cars are passing in one direction. or you might think it as a meeting room, one motion sensor installed at the meeting room, I want to show people whether the meeting room is available or not. so when motion sensor detects, the room is showing occupied for some time, if in the last 10 minutes, more motion activities received,  the occupied status will be longer, otherwise the occupied status time is shorter.

Comment: you should start with looking at the data. maybe you could show some graphs? otherwise, unless one worked on a similar application, it's impossible to suggest anything of use to you